# How to change oledb connection string dynamically, so it can be used for each target machine?

Tags: c#, connection-string

i am developing a win form project in c#. 
I am facing a problem, I am using a `.mdb` db file, and a connection string to use it e.g. `@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\mohan\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\AotoInformation\AotoInformation\common\appDb.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"`

Now I am making an `.exe` file of my project, but when someone install this `.exe` to his system, this connection string can't work.

How can I get a connection string that can be used on every target machine, no matter where user install the app?

Comment: Can you put the connection string in the app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

set the connection string in your code instead of config file. you can find app root path  using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.

Comment: thanx for your attention, this gives me a path for my app in my pc.But where and how should i keep the DB file in target machine so that i can get a general connection string???

Answer (score 0):

Connection string is merely a string.. So initially you can keep it anything like
`..Data Source=@mdbFilePath..` when requesting for connection string, replace `@mdbFilePath` with your mdb filepath...